# Don't understand how this conversion works

Tags: python, variables, type-conversion

So I was doing an exercise where I need it to turn some integers into strigs so I can concatenate them, BUT after that, I needed to make operations with them.
So I was stuck there until I saw the answer and didn't understand why it worked.

```
score = int(str(true_score) + str(love_score))

if score < 10 or score > 90:
  print(f"Your score is {score}, you go together like coke and mentos.")
elif score >= 40 and score <= 50:
  print(f"Your score is {score}, you are alright together.")
else:
  print(f"Your score is {score}.")
```

I wanted to make 5 and 3 to 53 , hence the string conversion. But I needed to do comparisons in a if statement (it wouldn't let me compare str with int) with them. This person turn them into a int, while at the same time working as a string? I don't understand how that worked.

Comment: No, it's not working as a string.  `score` is an `int`.  You have no string variables here at all.  The f-string is able to handle most types directly, so `f"...{score}..."` will convert the integer to a string for printing.

Comment: Read the parenthesized statement in the first line inside to out.  The two strings (inner parens) are concatenated, and then the resulting string value is converted back into an `int` (outermost parens), which is assigned to `score`.  By the time it’s assigned to `score` those string values effectively no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to believe that score is a string, which it is not, there is an int conversion surrounding the string concatenation, meaning that score is an int , hope this helps!